# Homestead error

Tags: vagrant, homestead

My homestead urls are not working any more. When I ping 172.100.1.2 I receive an reply. Also when I ping domain.dev I receive a reply. What could be wrong?

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "172.100.1.2"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: site.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site/public
    - map:  site.dev2
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site2
    - map: site3.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site3
    - map: site4.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site4/public
    - map: site5.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site5/public
    - map: site6.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site6/public
    - map: site7.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site7
    - map: site8.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site8

databases:
    - homestead



# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

/etc/hosts:

```
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##        
127.0.0.1
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
172.100.1.2   site2.dev 
172.100.1.2   site2.dev
172.100.1.2   site3.dev
172.100.1.2   site4.dev
172.100.1.2   site5.dev
172.100.1.2   site6.dev 
172.100.1.2     site7.dev
172.100.1.2    site8.dev
```

None of the urls is working anymore. If I visit one the error is:

The site is not available. Connection refused.

Comment: What urls do you open? Does http://site2.dev:8000/ work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `databases:` list in the Homestead.yaml file should match the list in your hosts file, like so:

```
databases:
    - site
    - site1
    - site2
    - site3
    - site4
    - site5
    - site6
    - site7
    - site8
```

You're also missing the line for site.dev in your hosts file: `172.100.1.2   site.dev`